# How to use a Obj-C #define from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i like use code builder with #define.

for example

Obj-c:

```
#define CBCaseStringFromEnum(_rValue_,_index_,_type_) \
   case _type_: _rValue_ = [@""#_type_"" substringFromIndex:_index_]; break
```

but how it resolved from swift?

i have  many

```
var varName: TypeName! {
  get {
     return self.configuration.varName
  }
  set(value) {
     self.configuration.varName = value
  }
}
```

i need resolve this from #define
how i can?

Comment: You don't need defines in Swift. It's pretty hard to see what you are you trying to do but in Swift you definitely don't need macros for it.

Comment: no, i need create property in class. it the codeBuilder. i don't can create property with global func

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can't use `#define` instead you can declare a global function and use it when required.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no other way... this way out - copy from target class varsLists

```
   var menuTitleColor: UIColor?
   var menuBackgroundColor: UIColor!
   var menuBackgroundOpacity: CGFloat!
   var menuHighliteBackgroundColor: UIColor!
   var menuItemColor: UIColor?
   var menuSelectedItemColor: UIColor?
```

and applay replace

```
var\s(.*):.*
$0 { \n get { return self.configuration.$1 } set(value) {self.configuration.$1 = value} }
```